# tidb grafana no data points

Tags: grafana, prometheus, tidb

I use tidb database, but when I want to build monitor. the grafana can't display data. It display "no data points".  I check the network in the chrome. and docker logs. they look like right. I don't know why.

Sorry, I want to ask question,but I don't have reputation to post images. so I write the issue in the github.

https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/issues/7509#issuecomment-416438806

Comment: Hi @googo have you installed TSDB Dash board plugin in grafana if not please install from here https://grafana.com/plugins/opentsdb

Comment: No,  but I have already solve this problems.  the reason is pushgateway (0.5.1) have some problems. It can't get data by http://xx.x.x.x:9091/metrics.  Then I rollback version to 0.4.1. It's work well.

Comment: ok good post your  answer for this question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your feedback. You need to use pushgateway v0.4.0 instead of pushgateway (0.5.1).
You could try https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-docker-compose or https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-operator directly.
We're working on remove pushgateway, and use prometheus to pull metrics directly.